# System.AccessViolationException occur from System.Net.Http C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
using (var ct = new Google.Apis.SearchConsole.v1.SearchConsoleService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
 {
    ApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleSearchApiKey"],
    ApplicationName = "my info"
 }))
 {

    html = ct.HttpClient.GetStringAsync("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(gameName) + "+origin+pc+game").Result;
 }

 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(html);

 var glist = doc.DocumentNode.GetById("search")?.GetByClass("g");
 if (glist != null)
 {
    var off = glist.First();
    var a = off.GetByTag("a").FirstOrDefault();

    if (a != null)
    {
       var url = a.GetAttributeValue("href", "");

       if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
       {
          url = WebUtility.UrlDecode(url);
          url = url.Substring(url.IndexOf("?q=") + 3);
          url = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf('&'));

          gameUrl = url;
          return stuff;
       }
    }
 }
```

When reach `ct.HttpClient.GetStringAsync`, I got beautiful error page:

> Application: MyApp.exe
>       Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>       Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>       Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
>          at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
>          at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync(System.Uri, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption, System.Threading.CancellationToken)

Why ?

Comment: So we can ignore the code starting from `HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();`?

Comment: What does this `BaseClientService` do? Are there any overrides or custom handlers or delegates? Under normal conditions, a user is allowed use a http connection.

Comment: @Stefan: the error has nothing to do with `HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();` ... `BaseClientService` is from Google Search API nuget package

Comment: Yes, so please, if it's not relevant for the question, remove it ;-)

Comment: What kind of application is this? Xamarin? Asp.Net? Access violation can be thrown by the OS.  So what's the host?

Comment: Does the same exception happen if you run your app as administrator?

Comment: @Stefan: It is WPF application. I hosted application on Amazon Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.

Comment: @ThomasK: Yes, even I run application with admin rights